# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_keycloak.decorators'

Tags: python, django, keycloak

I am trying to integrate Keycloak with django, therefore, I am using **django_keycloak** to work it out. However, when I run the migration the following exception is being thrown:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_keycloak.decorators'

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Is django-keyloack properly installed? Just in case run pip list to make sure it will show up in installed packages list. If it is properly instaled though, maybe double check if you have imported **decorators** module correctly in your code.

```
from django_keycloak.decorators import keycloak_protect
```

What happened to me plenty of times when I recently installed the **django_keycloak** package or made changes to my Django project, I had to restart my development server. Sometimes, changes in the environment require a server restart to take effect.

***EDIT:***
So I will assume that you have installed django-keycloack with command:
pip install django-keycloak

Configure Keycloak settings in your Django project's settings.py file. You'll need to provide the Keycloak server URL, realm name, client ID, and client secret. Here's an example configuration:

```
 KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL = 'https://keycloak.example.com/auth'
KEYCLOAK_REALM = 'your-realm'
KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID = 'your-client-id'
KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET = 'your-client-secret'
```

Then define Django views and secure them with Keycloak authentication using the @keycloak_protect decorator:

```
from django_keycloak.decorators import keycloak_protect

@keycloak_protect
def my_view(request):
    # Your view logic here
    ...
```

Use the @keycloak_roles_required decorator to restrict access to specific roles:

```
from django_keycloak.decorators import keycloak_roles_required

@keycloak_roles_required(roles=['admin'])
def admin_view(request):
    # Your admin view logic here
    ...
```

Configure Keycloak middleware in your Django project's settings.py file to enable Keycloak authentication middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django_keycloak.middleware.KeycloakMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Thanks @Magico Coding for your quick response. Do you have some sample scripts of your implementation or may be some github source? That would help me lot. Thanks again in advance.

Comment: @YasirArefin sure my friend. This github repository right here basically provides a complete example of integrating Keycloak with Django. You can find there also sample code for configuring Keycloak, setting up Django views, and securing endpoints with Keycloak authentication.  https://github.com/Peter-Slump/django-keycloak-example

Comment: Thanks again. But the link are not working for neither of them. Can you check again please?

Comment: ah allright this I had from last year saved, well give me couple of minutes I am gonna write it down for you personally in the edit answer

Comment: @YasirArefin check and let me know if that helped

Comment: I tried like this before. No luck.